# Route Template not working with FromQuery attribute

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using below routing and it works fine-

```
[HttpGet("{id}/{category}")]
public ActionResult<Pet> GetById(int id, string category, [FromQuery] string position)
```

The URL for a record with id = 1000, category = "Native" and position = "Mid" looks like - https://localhost:12345/api/v1/Pets/1000/Native?position=mid

Now I want to make Category parameter also to be fetched as FromQuery. I am trying to make changes as follows

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<Pet> GetById(int id, [FromQuery]string category, [FromQuery] string position)
```

But it does not work and gives 500 error. The url looks like -
https://localhost:12345/api/v1/Pets/1000?category=Native&position=Mid

Can anyone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here? Why it is working with simple fromQuery parameter and not with multiples?

Comment: a minor improvement would be using {id:int}

Comment: @monty Yes it seems to be working with your solution. However, I also observed if 1st parameter is string, then the solution does not work. {id:string}... Is there any restriction or specific reason for this? I have one more method with same issue and Id parameter is string.

Comment: may there are two routes to the pet controller having the pattern /pet/string. If that is the case the logic would not know which of the two to pick.

Comment: Yes! this is correct @monty. I have another method having pattern pet/string however, it have only one string parameter. Is there any way I can change my method so that it would work

Comment: I can modify the route to something like WildLife/pet/string but is there any other way without modifying the url pattern?

Comment: As far as I remember the url (patterns) must be unique in order to get the route mapping to work. Unfortunatly I don't remember any workarounds, just good design :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that you've two conflicting routes, each expecting a different parameter type from the route (i.e., one expecting a string and the other expecting an integer), Adding a route constraint to one of them will solve the problem. And the easiest way to do it is by adding ":int" to the action method you've posted here as @monty suggested in the comments. Below is a working example

```
[Route("api/v1/pets")]
public class PetsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{name}")]
    public ActionResult<Pet> GetByName(string name, [FromQuery]string category, [FromQuery] string position)
    {
        return new Pet()
        {
            Name = "Cat"
        };;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public ActionResult<Pet> GetById(int id, [FromQuery]string category, [FromQuery] string position)
    {
        return new Pet()
        {
            Name = "Dog"
        };;
    }
}
```